# Use of the Wilcoxon rank-sum test on two samples where the elements of one sample make up some of the elements of the other?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two samples to compare and I want to determine if they are statistically similar or different. Both are measurements of the same property on the same material. Lets say X contains 25 elements and Y contains 125 elements. 25 of the 125 elements in Y are the same ones that are in X. So X is a subset of Y. Is it incorrect to use the Wilcoxon-rank sum test? If so, can anyone recommend an alternative test? The data distributions are approximately normal but are not technically normal when I test them so a non-parametric test is probably best.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically similar"?

Comment: Wilcoxon test may answer your question, however, it was not created to answer exactly this question. I think what are looking into is Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: By statistically similar, I mean, were both samples selected from populations having 'the same' distribution

Comment: Can you just remove the 25 elements from Y ? So that your two groups are 25 "X & Y" and 100 "Y & not-X" ?

Comment: I cannot, its necessary to leave the repeated elements in as these make up a large part of the distribution of measurements

Comment: @GermanDemidov Thanks for your suggestion. Just checked and Kolmogorov-Smirnov gives the same results as Wilcoxon. So would KS technically be the 'more correct' test to use in this case?

Comment: @JoeyO'Donnell that's actually a tricky question. KS and Wilcoxon test can not give the same results since they test different hypothesis, but it is fine. I'd address to the first comment to your question - it depends on which question you want to answer. So far, it seems that you need some answer, but you do not care about the question.

Comment: ah, no, may be it is correct. Actually, no matter which one you use, you kinda show that there is a difference between distributions.

Comment: @GermanDemidov I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, I've ran both tests in Matlab (ranksum and kstest2) and they both output the same results for the hypothesis test. In essence, I thought both tests were checking if my two distributions are similar (accept null hypothesis) or different (reject null hypothesis)?

Comment: Check the 2nd example from here - https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/stat_nonparametric_tests_dont_compa.htm?toc=0&printWindow - Wilcoxon test (Mann-Whitney one) may give a non-significant p-value even if 2 distributions are really different. Because it is answering a different question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann–Whitney_U_test

Comment: @GermanDemidov Okay, I understand your point now. Both are about showing a difference but they do it in very different ways. The question I want to answer using a statistical test is, does the 25 measurements in X give an accurate representation (similar means & standard deviation) of the 125 measurements in Y? Is the Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test a correct way to do this?

Comment: @JoeyO'Donnell you need to perform a totally different analysis then. You need to resample 25 measurements 10.000 times and estimate mean and standard deviation from there. Then you compare your distributions with what you actually observe and make a conclusion. This is essentially a subsample from the same population, you do not need a test to answer that they come from the same distribution.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica The question seems clear to me. I don't understand why it was closed as unclear. It is, however, essentially a duplicate.

Comment: @JoeyO'Donnell All the tests being considered in the discussion here assume independence, which you don't have if you include the same observations in both samples. If you adjust them to properly account for this dependence the result is *exactly* the same as leaving out the common observations (which is obvious, since the difference between an observation and itself contributes *literally nothing* to information about what is different between the groups). It doesn't matter how big a fraction of the whole these observations are, they contain *zero* information about the hypothesis.

Comment: @Glen_b Does "similar" mean having same mean, same median, same shape, same range.... or something else?  The OP answered in a comment that he means "similar distribution"

Comment: Exactly what is being tested isn't directly relevant to the problem at hand (having the same data in both samples) -- the response ("don't do that, and here's why") is the same whatever the test would be.